# Access to notable types in Freebase without using Freebase API

Tags: freebase

I am looking for Freebase notable type of all entities in ClueWeb09 corpus. I got this error **Freebase API User Rate Limit Exceeded** when I use freebase API. I tried to use Freebase data dumps but, there is no notable type in predicates.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicates http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.notable_for and  http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.notable_types both appear in the current Freebase dump.